# How to create openid provider

Tags: asp.net, openid, dotnetopenauth

I want to create my own OpenId Provider instead of using Google, Yahoo etc

I have just followed the below link for creating OpenID Client

https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/Creating-an-openid-relying-party-%28programatically%29

when I am entered https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id in the openId textbox, it just took the Authentication from the Google and return token with information like EmailID, UserName etc, Instead of this I want provide Authentication from my own Provider

Please help me to create OpenId Enabled Website.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DotNetOpenAuth provides classes and structures which enable you to easily
create OAuth Consumer or Provider and manipulate Tokens. However each both
Consumer and Provider have to decide on how to handle and store the
Tokens.

Please follow the links

1.
[Dotnetopenauth single sign on with custom identity provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291668/dotnetopenauth-single-sign-on-with-custom-identity-provider)

2.
http://hoonzis.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-dotnetopenauth-to-create-oauth.html

Second link explains in details. it also has a link to download source
code so you can refer to that. I want you to create your own sample based
on #2 as he is using LINQ TO SQL.